# How to use question mark in query?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I use gorm and postgresql9.4.

The operator `?|` is used in my query.

```
DB.Where(`a->'b' ?| ARRAY['1','2','3'] `)
```

print sql:

```
WHERE  a->'b' | ARRAY['1','2','3']
```

The operator `?|` be converted `|`. This is not what I want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's a known [issue](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/issues/533). Intended or not, `???` will escape the question mark.